# Не работает position:fixed в Android Browser 4.1.2

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

Добрый день, уважаемые знатоки.
Внимание вопрос: я создал сайт, в котором верхнее меню навигации имеет `position:fixed`, чтобы оставаться всегда видимым при скроле страницы,однако на разных устройствах клиента это меню при вертикальном скролле страницы вниз начинает тоже двигаться вниз, и исчезает впоследствии совсем. Увидеть такое поведение смог только на эмуляторе на сайте https://www.manymo.com/ - действительно, в стандартном браузере оно так себя ведёт. На моём HTC Desire с Android 4.1.1 такого поведения не наблюдаю ни в дефолтовом браузере, ни в остальных (Chrome, FF), в Safari на планшете с последним iOS тоже работает корректно. На домашнем ПК в "популярных" браузерах работает корректно.
Гугл о такой проблеме не знает, либо я некорректно формулирую запросы.
Подскажите, как можно отловить/решить этот баг.
Код меню достаточно обычный:

```
<nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-2"></div>
     <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-8"></div>
     <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

и соответственно стили:

```
nav {
  position: fixed !important;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0 25px;
}
```

Сайт, как видите, делаю на Bootstrap 3. Особые чужие скрипты не использую, а те, которые дополнительно написал сам, пробовал отключать.

Comment: может стоит попробовать добавить какой-нибудь там top: 0; left: 0 ? И еще вот: In Android 4.0-4.3 position:fixed inside an iframe will cause unexpected behviour.
Link:
http://caniuse.com/#search=position%3Afixed

Comment: @needhate , похоже, `top:0` - именно то, что было нужно! спасибо. как это часто бывает - какая-то мелочь вылетела из головы и взорвала мозг при отладке. можете оформить как ответ - плюсану вам. большое пасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно добавить в стили:

```
nav {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0; <------
  left:0; <------
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0 25px;
}
```